# Как сделать выход с сайта?

Tags: php

Для запароливания админки сайта используется скрипт:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))

{
        Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
        Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
        exit();
}

else {
        if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
                $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
        }

        $query = "SELECT pass FROM userlist WHERE user='".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']."'";
        $lst = @mysql_query($query);

        if (!$lst)
        {
            Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
        Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
        exit();
        }

        if (mysql_num_rows($lst) == 0)
        {
           Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
           Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
           exit();
        }

        $pass =  @mysql_fetch_array($lst);
        if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']!= $pass['pass'])
        {
            Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
           Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
           exit();
        }

}

?>
```

Как сделать выход из админки? Уже удалял $_SERVER... Ничего не работает.

Comment: хм, $_SERVER говорите?

> Переменная $_SERVER - это массив, содержащий информацию, такую как заголовки, пути и местоположения скриптов. Записи в этом массиве создаются веб-сервером. Нет гарантии, что каждый веб-сервер предоставит любую из них; сервер может опустить некоторые из них или предоставить другие, не указанные здесь. Тем не менее, многие эти переменные присутствуют в » спецификации CGI/1.1, так что вы можете их ожидать их реализации и в конкретном веб-вервере.

я не уверен, что `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` у вас работает вообще :)

вам бы использовать куки, или сессии...

Comment: Закрыть окно браузера!

Comment: Ну я $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] на другой странице вывожу, и выводится. Значит работает.

Comment: не думаю что $_SERVER будет работать так, как вам хочется :) подозреваю, что любая запись в ней, будет дублироваться на всех клиентах, т.е. на всех пользователей в сети, со всеми вытекающими последствиями )

Comment: [Евгений Ваганович][1], залогиньтесь под своим именем.

  [1]: http://lurkmore.to/%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BD

Comment: @Виктор Павлов зачем дублируешь вопросы? )
[тема2][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/231057/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно просто еще раз отослать запрос аутентификации.

Нужно чуток допилить начало:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || $_GET['action'] == 'logout')
    {
    Header ("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Admin Page\"");
    Header ("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized"); // может, можно и 1.1?
    exit();
    }
else
    {
    echo '<a href="?action=logout">Logout</a>'
    }
```

Но с сессиями, все же, добротнее будет.

Answer (score 0):

Самый гуманный и не сложный способ - организовать регистрацию и авторизацию через куки или сессию, а по нажатию на определённую ссылку - просто убить текущий сеанс, вот и все дела ))

Comment: а что он сказал правильно, я бы уточни, использовать куки с временным ключом, какой меняется в определенный интервал - одно из лучших решений. Для этого желательно в куки создать 2 поля ( ID пользователя, временный код)

Comment: Вопрос был именно по этому скрипту авторизации. В вопросе было ясно сказано, что удаление сессии не даёт результата.

Comment: > что удаление сессии не даёт результата.

это где была сказано?